# How do I keep a kivymd toolbar on every screen?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to create an app in kivymd with a toolbar at the top of every screen. When I change screens, is there a way to keep the same toolbar at the top of the new screen without copying and pasting all the code for the toolbar again?

Answer (score 0):

*u will have to create a main class that all classes will inherit that bar from it.*

Comment: I’m kinda new to Kivy so could you explain this a little more? I think i understand what you are saying but I’m not 100% sure.